# Dissolving/aggregating/combining points by proximity using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-survey123

I'm teaching a GIS lab where we have groups of students go out and collect GPS coordinates of security phones on campus using the Survey 123 app.  Because of the way the it is set up, multiple groups are surveying the same phones and uploading them.  However, each phone's GPS gives a slightly different location.  So we end up with having multiple records of the same phone a few meters apart from each other.  If they were spatially coincident, its easy to use the dissolve function, but this doesn't work when they are not co-located.

Is there a relatively simple way we could have intro level GIS students go about "dissolving" these points?

For reference, we have about 25 phones they are collecting data for.  We could have them select the first record of each manually if necessary, but I'd rather try to show them a more justifiable approach.

If I were tackling this problem myself, I'd just use python to calculate the mean center of the multiple records for each phone.  But I don't really want to make them deal with trying to use a custom Python script or anything.

Comment: Sounds like a way to learn how to use Near.

Comment: Add coordinates, summarize by phoneid, mean x, mean y.

Comment: @FelixIP, Good suggestion.  I'll try this.  Thanks!

Comment: Lazy one: dissolve to multipoint; minimum geometry - convex hull; feature to point (inside:)